# Cycles in stirling cycle numbers example

Tags: combinatorics, discrete-mathematics, stirling-numbers

I was reading about Stirling cycle numbers which count the permutations of $n$ objects that have just $k$ cycles.
An example I read mentioned the $6$ permutations of $3$ objects are classified as:
$1$ cycle: $(123)(132)$
$2$ cycles: $(12)(3)\space \space \space(13)(2)\space \space \space(23)(1)$
$3$ cycles: $(1)(2)(3)$
I am not clear what do we mean by cycles in this example?

Comment: Make sure you understand [cyclic permutations](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cyclic_permutation) and [cycle notation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Permutation#Cycle_notation). Also, the "1 cycle" row consists of two separate permutations: $(123)$ and $(132)$ (there should be a big space between them like in your "2 cycles" row.

Comment: @angryavian: Does that mean that $(123)(132)$ is not one cycle?

Comment: It actually simplifies to the identity permutation actually, so it is the same as $(1)(2)(3)$.

Comment: @angryavian: I think I understood the cyclic permutation idea from the link you shared but not the cycle notation. Is cycle notation related with stirling numbers?

Comment: @angryavian: I think $(123)\space \space(132)$ should mean $1$ to $2$, $2$ to $3$ and $3$ to $1$ for $(123)$. While for $(132)$ it should mean $1$ to $3$, $3$ to $2$ and $2$ to $1$. So why are they the same as $(1) \space (2) \space (3)$ that map $1$ to $1$, $2$ to $2$ and $3$ to $3$ i.e. everything remains fixed?

Comment: I am only pointing out that you should add spaces between $(123)$ and $(132)$ to make it clear that they are separate permutations and not a product (like $(12)(3)$ in the second row).

Comment: @angryavian: So without the space they are the same as $(1)(2)(3)$?